# Gradient of matrix valued function

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am wondering if its possible to obtain an analytic expression for the gradient of $$f(B) = (A - B)\left[(A - B)'(A - B)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
with respect to $B$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{s \times t}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{s \times t},$ and $(A - B)$ has rank $t$ and $t$ distinct singular values.

Trying to vectorize the expression (since gradient of vector with respect to vector has analytic form): 
$$ {\rm vec}\left(A\left[(A - B)'(A - B)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) -  \left(\left[(A - B)'(A - B)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \otimes I\right) {\rm vec}(B),$$ 
but since $B$ cannot be vectorized inside the square root, I'm not sure how (or if its possible to) proceed.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $C^{-\frac12}$? Do you mean "The matrix $D$ such that $D^2C=CD^2=I$"? Because $D$ is not at all uniquely defined in that case.

Comment: Good point! Yes, your definition is what I mean -- but I should have clarified that the singular values of $(A - B)$ are unique. This, along with my earlier statement that $(A - B)$ is rank $t$, should address any issues of uniqueness.

Comment: whether the singular values are unique or not doesn't really help: For example, if $C$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal $1,4,9,16,25,...$, then D could be any of the diagonal matrices with diagonals $\pm1,\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{3},\pm\frac{1}{4},\pm\frac{1}{5},...$. Each eigenvalue (repeated or not) of $C$ gives you a choice of sign for the eigenvalue of $D$. Unless - do you know that $A-B$ is positive definite, and you're only choosing positive square roots of the positive eigenvalues of $A-B$ to form $(A-B)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: $A - B$ is not even square, so it couldn't be positive definite. The matrix I am taking the square root of is $(A-B)'(A-B)$, which is $t \times t$ and positive definite since $A - B$ has rank $t$.

Comment: I may be missing something though, so I appreciate the questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new variable
$$\eqalign{
 X &= B-A \quad\implies dX = dB \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new matrix.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= -X(X^TX)^{-1/2} \cr
}$$
Multiply each side by its transpose and calculate their differentials.
$$\eqalign{
 FF^T &= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T = XX^+ \cr
 dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T
 &= dX\,X^+ + X\,dX^+ \cr
 &= dX\,X^+ + X^{+T}dX^T(I-XX^+) - XX^+dX\,X^+ \cr
 &= (I-XX^+)\,dX\,X^+ + X^{+T}dX^T(I-XX^+) \cr
 &= P\,\,dX\,X^+ + X^{+T}dX^TP \cr
}$$
where $X^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse, and $P$ is an orthogonal projector into the nullspace of $X$.

Vectorize and solve for the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\Big((F\otimes I) + (I\otimes F)K\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dF) 
&= \Big((X^{+T}\otimes P) + (P\otimes X^{+T})K\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dB) \cr
M\,df &= N\,db \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= M^+N \cr
}$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product.